# Build error with PostSharp on framework "netcoreapp2.0" and RID "debian.8-x64"

Tags: c#, build, .net-core, postsharp, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project targeting net461 (win7-x64) and netcoreapp2.0 (debian.8-x64).

When I build the project on my desktop everything works great.
Build is done by VS or in command line :

`dotnet publish -c "Release" -o "xxxx" -f "net461" -r "win7-x64" xxxxx.csproj`

`dotnet publish -c "Release" -o "xxxx" -f "netcoreapp2.0" -r "debian.8-x64" xxxxx.csproj`

But when it is done by our build server (triggered by Gitlab and runned by the Gitlab Runner in Powershell) everything build correctly in **net461** but failed for **netcoreapp2.0**.

The error seems to be produced by Postsharp.
With the version **5.1.3-alpha** I have an error about an assembly not found :

> Error PS0264: Cannot find the assembly 'flexcel, version=6.19.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=cb8f6080e6d5a4d6'. Build your project with detailed verbosity to see the assembly loading log.

=> Weird fact, the case of the assembly is not correct, it is Flexcel, and again, it works well in net461.

So I tried to update Postsharp to 5.1.9-preview and now I have an another error :
`POSTSHARP30`

> Error :  [C:\Build\Gitlab\Runner\builds\17fef169\0\xxxx.csproj]
>            C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\postsharp\5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp.targets(340,5): error : The process "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\postsharp\5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp-Tools.exe" failed with exit code 2. [C:\Build\Gitlab\Runner\builds\17fef169\0\xxxx.csproj]

For both versions (5.1.3-alpha and 5.1.9-preview), if I log in the build server and run the dotnet publish command in a console, it works well. The issue happens only when this is done by the CI build process.

Does anyone encountered the same kind of errors ?

Thanks.

Luc

Answer (score 1):

PostSharp does not support building on Linux yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have precised, builds are done on Windows Server Core 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why or how, unbelievable, but without a change it is now working...

Really really strange

Comment: Failure of `PostSharp-Tools.exe` are temporary and can be typically solved by cleaning up the `C:\ProgramData\PostSharp` folder.